# Does holding a weak reference prevent a retain cycle from being considered a leak?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

Consider the following code. I create 2 Foo objects and give each of them a strong reference to the other:

```
class Foo: {
  var otherFoo: Foo?
  var value: Int
}

class FooContainer {

  weak var aFoo: Foo?

  var firstFoo = Foo(otherFoo: nil, value: 1)
  var secondFoo = Foo(otherFoo: firstFoo, value: 2)
  firstFoo.otherFoo = secondFoo //The 2 foo objects now form a retain cycle
  aFoo = firstFoo //save a weak reference to one of the Foo objects    
}
```

The above is certainly a retain cycle, but is it a memory leak? I save a weak reference to one of the objects into an instance variable.

Neither the Instruments Leaks instrument nor Xcode's memory graph utility flag the above as a leak. If you remove the assignment to `aFoo`, the 2 `Foo` objects **are** flagged as leaks.

Is a retain cycle only considered a leak when there are NO outside references to it?

Comment: Sorry, you're both right. That should have been `class` Foo, not `struct` foo. I wasn't thinking. Off to correct my question.

Comment: Cyclical object graphs aren't bad.They're very useful, such as for modelling graph algorithms.  The leaks caused by poorly implemented cyclical object graphs are bad. And by poorly implemented, I those which cause *strong* retain cycles

Comment: Re cyclical object graphs, I understand their usefulness. Doubly linked lists are a simple example. The usual convention in Cocoa is to assign a "forward" and "backward" direction and make the backward-pointing link weak. Otherwise, if you have cyclical strong references you have to be **really** careful about housekeeping.

Comment: I  expected Xcode/Instruments to treat a pair of strongly linked objects to be treated as a memory leak unless there was also a **strong** reference "anchoring" them elsewhere to your object graph.

Comment: And? Isn't that the case?

Comment: @Alexander, Xcode only flags a retain cycle as a leak if it's completely orphaned with NO other references, strong *or* weak.

Comment: Interesting. I think that has to do with the implementation of `weak` references in Swift. https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-12-11-swift-weak-references.html https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html

Answer (score 5):

A *retain cycle* is a "cycle" of objects, each holding a strong reference
to the next one, so that none of them can be deallocated.

A *leak* is allocated memory which is not "accessible", i.e. there are no
pointers to it.

In your case, the two `Foo` instances build a retain cycle, but it is
not a leak (as long as the `FooContainer` instance exists)
because the instances are accessible through the `aFoo`
property.

It is irrelevant here that  `aFoo` is a weak property: The `firstFoo` 
instance is never deallocated (as part of a retain cycle), therefore
the weak reference is never nullified.

Comment: I frequently hear non-leak lost memory referred to as "abandoned" or "orphaned".  Retain cycle is just one case of this.

Comment: Should we distinguish between `retain cycle` and `strong retain cycle`? Is it still called a `retain cycle` even if it has weak references that don't cause a `strong retain cycle`?

Comment: I've only ever heard "retain cycle" used in reference to two objects keeping each other alive via strong references.

Comment: Point of clarification: Not just two objects. You can have n-way retain cycles of various topologies. A Hypercube, for example.